# How to set different effects in nivo-slider

Tags: javascript, plugins

I've got a nivo-slider on my site, but there aren't any effects except slidesUp, even though I have set the default installation.

```
         <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">
      <div class="ribbon"></div>
      <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider">

  <img src="/upload/banners/image1.png" border="0" alt=""/>
  <img src="/upload/banners/image2.png" border="0" alt=""/>
  <img src="/upload/banners/image3.png" border="0" alt=""/>  

      </div>
     </div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>
```

and in header:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/scripts/jquery.nivo.slider.pack.js"></script>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/css/nivo-slider.css"/>
```

What should I do to make it works properly?

Comment: Yeah, sorry for delay it was just my simple fault I've created img tags with the same image - therefor some effects were excepted.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

zeusakm.
Check your code and look for this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});
</script>
```

You have to call the 'effect' option and then you can set it. How?:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).load(function() {
    $('#slider').nivoSlider({
        effect:'random'
    });
});
</script>
```

The effect parameter can be any of the following:

- sliceDown
- sliceDownLeft
- sliceUp
- sliceUpLeft
- sliceUpDown
- sliceUpDownLeft
- fold
- fade
- random
- slideInRight
- slideInLeft
- boxRandom
- boxRain
- boxRainReverse
- boxRainGrow
- boxRainGrowReverse

Complete reference: http://nivo.dev7studios.com/#usage

Comment: How can I add a new effect ??

Answer (score 3):

Also the order of the scripts apparently matter:

1. jQuery JS file must be linked somewhere in your HTML file.
2. Nivo Slider JS file must be linked AFTER the jQuery JS file.
3. Slider-specific controls (such as "effect:'fade'") must be in script
   tags AFTER the Nivo Slider JS file.

An easy worksround or alternative providing more control is to specify

```
<img src="mypic.jpg" alt="" data-transition="fade"/>
```

which also lets you specify the effect per picture.

Comment: it's clear from the code shared that the jquery js file and the nivo slider js file are linked in the header.