# NivoSlider for Umbraco

Tags: asp.net, slider, slideshow, umbraco

I needed a slider for my Umbraco projects so i search about it and find [this link](http://our.umbraco.org/projects/website-utilities/nivoslider-for-umbraco/).I downloaded and read [this pdf](http://our.umbraco.org/FileDownload?id=2974) about it.then create a required Media Type called ‘NivoSliderImage’.but i can not understand how to use this media type and package?

Comment: this link is useful:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511074/how-to-set-different-effects-in-nivo-slider

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to create a new MediaType and this can be done within Umbraco in the "Settings" section. There is a folder under the Settings tree called "Media Types".

Create a new Media Type here and follow the instructions in the PDF. The media type will need to be called "NivoSliderImage" it will need the properties adding that are detailed in the PDF.

You will then need to create a folder in the "Media Library" section, specifically for adding media that you have created from the Media Type object "NivoSliderImage". For example, once the folder is created, you can right-click on the folder, select "Create" and then select "NivoSliderImage" from the menu in the box.

Once you have a few images in the folder, go to the "Settings > Templates" folder and select a template. Place your cursor where you wish to put your nivo slider and click the "Insert Macro" in the toolbar. Hopefully, there will be an option called NivoSlider. When you select this, you will be given a range of options as detailed in the PDF. The top option will be which Media Library folder you wish to use. You should choose the one that you created and placed your NivoSliderImage images in.

Comment: thanks,and in this link :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6511074/how-to-set-different-effects-in-nivo-slider    ,i see this tag : <img src="/upload/banners/image1.png" border="0" alt=""/>  ,is it Necessary؟