# How can I use vertical slider in my NopCommerce site home page?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, nopcommerce, jssor, nivo-slider

I'm using nopcommerce for my site and wanted to use vertical full width slides on home page. Nivo slider does not give any option to use vertical slides. Jssor slider has an option to use vertical slides but I don't know how to go for it.

Please suggest me some plugin available or how can I  the nopcpmmerce 3.80 code to use jssor slider in my installation. I would appreciate any quick help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response @Div. Is there any free plugin or some resource for this also?

Comment: Thanks @Div, but it will not solve my problem. I need something like : http://www.jssor.com/demos/vertical-slider.slider. But what I have is horizontal slides with only transition effects.

Comment: Wow! But it will require some great deal of nopcommrce development knowledge I think and I'm fairly new in it as of now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125096/discussion-between-rashid-and-div).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @Div .... I used Jssor slider jquery in place of nivo by editing my Nivo slider plugin. I'm able to see a vertical slider at homepage now, but it is giving a horizontal scroll bar and the image is not extending to full width instead it is giving white blank space in the right side. And also the scrollbar is making the page in the right side with white space and below the slider also. Please see the attached image for reference. Any help?

Comment: As of now it is on local system. If you need I can paste the code here.

Comment: I've created a new question available at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39910245/jssor-slider-horizontal-scroll-issue . Please help me thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As we discussed, you can use [QuickFlexSlider Widget](http://www.nopcommerce.com/p/1695/quickflexslider-widget-nop4youcom.aspx), which gives many cool features and also includes your requirement.

Or you can make changes `nivoslider plugin` to vertical effects refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6542281/4753489). I found same code in `jquery.nivo.slider.js`. So you can replace code in js file.

> It will require some great deal of nopcommrce development knowledge I
>   think and I'm fairly new in it as of now.

NopCommerce has pretty good document on [how to develop a plugin](http://docs.nopcommerce.com/display/nc/How+to+write+a+nopCommerce+plugin).

Comment: Thanks @Div. I used these effects but this did not solve my purpose. As I need pure vertical slides on my homepage, not only image transition effects. Thanks for your help though. I'll invest time to build a plugin later but at present I wanted a quick fix.